# how to read input from text input field and put input into div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to run this code.
the code should take a string as input and put that input to a div and calculate the width of the div.

here is code i have used.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" value="" name="input">
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">

<script>
var elem = '<div id="divitem" style="width:auto;"></div>';
$('body').append($(elem));
$("submit").click(function () {
var text = $(this).text();
value= $("input").val(text);
alert(value);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

but i am not getting any output. how to do this?
please help me.

Comment: what is `$("submit")` ?? it should be like `$('input[type=submit]')`

Comment: You should use 'submit' as $("input[type=submit]")

Comment: Actually, what's this code supposed to do?

Comment: i want this code to take input string from input field and append the input string to div and then find the width of div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this paps!

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CarloOV/CnT3e/)

This is similar to your problem.

HTML

```
<div id="container">
   <input type="text" value="" id="inputtext">
   <input type="button" value="submit" id="submit">
</div>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
    var elem = '<span id="divitem"></span>';

    $('#container').append($(elem));

    $("#submit").click(function () {     
        $('#divitem').html($('#inputtext').val());
        alert($('#divitem').width());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/D5n6H/)

To obtain value from a text field you need to use this,

```
$('input[name="input"]').val();
```

and not .text()

To answer your second question, you need to use this

```
$('#divitem').attr('style');
```

or

```
$('#divitem').attr('width');
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
$("submit").click(function () {
    var text = $(this).text();
    value= $("input").val(text);
    alert(value);
});
```

$(this) refers to the element that you select, which is the submit button.
You should replace the first line of the function with

```
$('input[name="input"]').text();
```

Finally, setting the html content of the div, will be done this way:

```
elem.html(test);
```

Hope this helps. Have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsFiddle for your question http://jsfiddle.net/N4zFZ/ in JavaScript

You can calculate width by

```
`var width = $('#divId').attr('width');`
```